# Android: Center an image horizontally based on another image (not on parent)

Tags: android

Is there a way to center an image horizontally based on another image? Could be from xml or coded.

For example one button on top and another button below (i.e. android:layout_below="@+id/button1"), but centered horizontally based on the first one.

Comment: In what GUI framework? Are you talking about HTML/CSS?

Comment: Yeah, definitely need a little more detail here.  While you are providing more details, is Javascript an option for you to use or are you looking for pure CSS....that is assuming that we are talking about HTML/CSS

Comment: My bad, I thought I was on an android forum or something, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is the second image the same size or smaller than the first? If so, you can align the left and right sides, and specify a centred fit...

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/secondImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/firstImage"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/firstImage"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/firstImage"
    android:scaleType="center" />
```

Comment: Nice, it does work when its smaller and I would never thought of aligning both sides. Unfortunately it "cuts" the image if its bigger :/